# Does using view page source on a possibly malicious site carry any real risks?

Tags: web-browser, vulnerability, source-code

As far as I know, `View page source` does not execute any JavaScript, but is that good enough?

- Could there in theory be any vulnerabilities in the HTML parser or something similar?
- Have there been any exploits in this area before?
- How realistic is it getting infected by viewing page source of a malicious website?

The theory kinda says it should be impossible, but I'm looking forward for other opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When viewing the page source, the browser renders the html code without interpretation, that means the scripts that are either embedded or called using the `<script/>` tag are not executed by the browser.
Any possible risk from displaying the code source would be brought by the browser (could be a bug or vulnerability) not the malicious page itself.

Comment: Has there been such a case when that happened?

Comment: not to my knowledge.