# Is Chrome's view-source dangerous when visiting malicious sites?

Tags: malware, web-browser, javascript, chrome, source-code

What are the risks of viewing the source code of malicious pages on Google Chrome?

I want to go directly to `view-source:https://example-site.com` to visit the sites without rendering anything malicious / executing any scripts.

I am aware that just visiting the source pages might not give much/any valuable information about potential malicious actors/scripts/payloads, I am simply wondering whether this is completely safe.

Are there any new potential vulnerabilities/exploits that I should be aware of?

Comment: See this answer : https://security.stackexchange.com/a/256612/21144

Comment: So am I correct in understanding that I could still be potentially vulnerable to a 0-day exploit of Chrome?

Comment: less likely with the major browsers as for now.

Comment: This is marked as duplicate, but the answer to this question here is actually better than the one in the linked question

Answer (score 2):

If there's a bug in how the browser fetches the code and displays it in the `view source` page then that could potentially result in your browser getting compromised. Or a vulnerability in the network or TLS stack.

Additionally, making the request will expose your IP address to whoever is running the server, which could potentially be a problem for you.

If you're dealing with sites that you know or suspect are malicious, you should be doing it in a sandbox/VM, to get an additional layer of protection.

Answer (score 1):

Viewing the source without viewing the page is safe from exploits that rely on JS being executed client side, since JS is not executed. So no need to worry about XSS or CSRF. However, there might be a few pitfalls:

- The browser requests the page, so you expose your IP. If the URL is from a spam email, it may be unique to you and expose the fact that your email is active.
- As others have pointed out, if there is some sort of buffer overflow or similar in your browser, it may lead to arbitrary code execution. The probability of this is low, and I would not worry about it.
- If you visit `view-source:https://example.com/delete-my-account`, your account might be deleted. This hinges on (a) the server performing state changing operations on GET requests, and (b) you being logged in. So maybe not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the page is parsed before you view its code or not.

If you visit the page and then see the source (e.g. right click on the page and select something like "view source") then the possible damage has already been done.

If you fetch the page and you view the content without parsing it, then there's no problem.

[view-source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View-source_URI_scheme) is suppposed to be a harmless action, that instructs the browser to fetch the page and then show its code, without parsing it. However, there have been some defects in the past in some browsers; whether a site that you visit uses a 0-day exploit that targets the browser's `view-source` functionality, is possible in principle, yes.